# Htaccess Redirect URL with two forward slashes (not double) won't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect from one domain to a new domain. At the same time, the URL structure has changed.

- Old: `https://www.olddomain.com/parentpage/oldtitle/`
- New: `https://www.newdomain.com/newtitle`

This is wordpress, and I placed this code above the Wordpress stuff, as well as tested it here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

1. I tried this, which doesn't work:

   ```
   Redirect 301 /parentpage/title https://www.newdomain.com/newtitle
   ```
2. Also, when testing it at https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, I do have this redirect:

   ```
   Redirect 301 /parentpage https://www.newdomain.com/parentpage
   ```

   The tester would skip my preferred redirect above, and use this one, leaving me with this, which does not exist:

   ```
   https://www.newdomain.com/parentpage/oldtitle
   ```

   Even when I place the preferred redirect above this one. I need both, unfortunately.
3. Have also tried the following RewriteRules (not all at the same time)

   ```
   ReWriteRule https://www.olddomain.com/parentpage/oldtitle/ https://www.newdomain.com/newtitle
   ReWriteRule /parentpage/oldtitle/ https://www.newdomain.com/newtitle
   ReWriteRule "https://www.olddomain.com/parentpage/oldtitle/" "https://www.newdomain.com/newtitle"
   ```

I think it has something to do with that second forward slash separating the parentpage name and page title, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by "two forward slashes (not double)"? What does "not double" mean?

Comment: Sorry, when I was searching Google, there were a lot of threads here, so I chose to post here.

When I tried to search for my problem (google, here, reddit etc.), search results usually returned a different problem, where users were having trouble with URLs with two double slashes or more, like this:
`www.domain.com//title`

Answer (score 1):

In RewriteRule it wouldn't match http or https in it, you may try following.

please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/parentage/oldtitle/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/newtitle [R=301,L]
```